# Area of a smooth parametrized surface

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $S=\mathbf{X}(D)=(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))$ be a smooth parametrized surface with $(s,t) \in\mathbf{R}^2$, where $D$ is the union of finitely many elementary regions in $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{X}:D\to \mathbf{R}^3 $ is of class $C^1$ and one-one except possibly along $\partial D$.
Let $\mathbf{T_s}$ be the tangent vector to the $s$-coordinate curve $\mathbf{X}(s,t_0)$ and let $\mathbf{T_t}$ be the tangent vector to $t$-coordinate curve $\mathbf{X}(s_0,t)$.

Consider now a small rectangular subset of $D$ whose lower left corner is at the point $(s_0,t_0)$ and whose width and height are respectively $\Delta s$ and $\Delta t$. The image of this rectangle under $\mathbf{X}$ is a piece of the underlying surface $S$ that is approximately the parallelogram with a corner at $\mathbf{X}(s_0,t_0)$ and spanned by the vectors $\mathbf{T_s}(s_0,t_0)\Delta s$ and $\mathbf{T_t}(s_0,t_0)\Delta t$. So the area of the piece is:$$\Delta A= \left \| \mathbf{T_s}(s_0,t_0)\Delta s \times  \mathbf{T_t}(s_0,t_0)\Delta t \right \|$$
At this time one may partition $D$ and construct the Riemann sum...
My Question is: why it is not possible to normalize the two vectors $\mathbf{T_t}$ and $\mathbf{T_s}$ without changing $\Delta A$? That is, as  $\Delta s$ and $\Delta t$ approach $0$ you should always "cover" the surface, shouldn't you? And if not why?

Comment: In what sense do you mean for $\bf T_t$ and $\bf T_s$ to be normalized?

Comment: Usually we define $\mathbf{T}_\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{T}_\mathbf{t}$ to be of unit length already. Multiplying by $\Delta s$ and $\Delta t$, respectively, tells us how big to make the tangent-parallelogram approximation whose projection onto $D$ is the $\Delta s$ by $\Delta t$ rectangle you mentioned.